# ReferenceError: window is not defined in keycloak-js

Tags: reactjs, keycloak

ReferenceError: window is not defined in keycloak-js. Its not clear what is causing this issue while running the ReactJS App using keycloak-js (15.0.1) against a keycloak 15 server

```
yarn run v1.22.5

$ nodemon ./server-build/index.js

[nodemon] 2.0.12

[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`

[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*

[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json

[nodemon] starting `node ./server-build/index.js`

/app/foo-web/node_modules/keycloak-js/dist/keycloak.js:63

})(window, function (sha256_imported, base64js_imported) {

   ^

 

ReferenceError: window is not defined

    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/foo-web/node_modules/keycloak-js/dist/keycloak.js:63:4)

    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)

    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)

    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)

    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)

    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)

    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)

    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/foo-web/server-build/index.js:1:716359)

    at a (/app/foo-web/server-build/index.js:1:110)

    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/foo-web/server-build/index.js:1:696707)

[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```